# Add a new confirmation page before saving

Tags: plugin-development, redirect, hooks

I'm going to add a hook that does some modifications of the text before saving. Before making the changes permanent, I would like the user to confirm the changes after a "save_post" hook. Is there a way to redirect to an intermediate page before finally saving?

Comment: Wouldn't a Javascript popup have the same effect? What are you trying to show in this screen? Ok/Cancel? - [Working example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74547/12615).