# Make featured image required

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, post-thumbnails

Is it possible to force user to set featured image on some types of posts. For example I've got custom post type `mm_photo` and I want to show some error message or somehow block user from publishing or updating post when there is no featured image set.

Comment: Have you also considered using fall-back images in your template if none is supplied? There was a similar question/answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410402/require-authors-to-set-featured-image-for-post)

Comment: Try to [adapt this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54279/12615) and update your Question. And [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) will help you write a better Q.

Answer (score 4):

Fairly simple using jQuery and global `$typenow` ex:

```
add_action('admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'my_publish_admin_hook');
add_action('admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'my_publish_admin_hook');
function my_publish_admin_hook(){
    global $typenow;
    if (in_array($typenow, array('post','page','mm_photo '))){
        ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
                    if (jQuery("#set-post-thumbnail").find('img').size() > 0) {
                        jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                        jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        alert("please set a featured image!!!");
                        jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                        jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>

        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13575967

To repeat the code from that answer:

```
function featured_image_requirement() {

     if(!has_post_thumbnail()) {

          wp_die( 'You forgot to set the featured image. Click the back button on your browser and set it.' ); 

     } 

}

add_action( 'pre_post_update', 'featured_image_requirement' );
```

Answer (score 0):

f you would like to require that all posts have a featured image before they can be published add this snippet to the functions.php of your wordpress theme. When you try and publish a post without a featured image you get an admin message “You must select Featured Image. Your Post is saved but it can not be published.”

```
add_action('save_post', 'heap_child_check_thumbnail');
add_action('admin_notices', 'heap_child_thumbnail_error');


function heap_child_check_thumbnail($post_id) {

  // change to any custom post type
  if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'mm_photo') {
    return;
  }


  if (!has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
    // set a transient to show the users an admin message
    set_transient("has_post_thumbnail", "no");
    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('save_post', 'heap_child_check_thumbnail');
    // update the post set it to draft
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'draft'));
    add_action('save_post', 'heap_child_check_thumbnail');
  }
  else {
    delete_transient("has_post_thumbnail");
  }

}

function heap_child_thumbnail_error() {
  if (get_transient("has_post_thumbnail") == "no") {
    echo "<div id='message' class='error'><p><strong>You must select Featured Image. Your Post is saved but it can not be published.</strong></p></div>";
    delete_transient("has_post_thumbnail");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not publish the post without the featured image.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', function ( $data, $postarr ) {
$post_id              = $postarr['ID'];
$post_status          = $data['post_status'];
$original_post_status = $postarr['original_post_status'];
if ( $post_id && 'publish' === $post_status && 'publish' !== $original_post_status ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    if ( post_type_supports( $post_type, 'thumbnail' ) && ! has_post_thumbnail( $post_id )) {
        $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
      }
}
return $data;
}, 10, 2 );
```

This will notify admin Feature image is required.

```
global $pagenow;
if ( $pagenow == 'post-new.php' || $pagenow == 'post.php' ) :
add_action( 'admin_notices', function () {
$post = get_post();
if ( 'publish' !== get_post_status( $post->ID ) && ! has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) { ?>
 <div id="message" class="error">
  <p> <strong>
   <?php _e( 'Please set a Featured Image. This post cannot be published without one.'); ?>
</strong> </p>
</div>
 <?php }
} );
endif;
```

Comment: How do you get rid of the "post published. View post" message?